# Individual Columns Password Protected

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-protection

Can individual columns be password protected for separate people, so that others can view information but only change data in their column?

Comment: What version of Excel? Would everyone be using Excel with macros?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You need to be connected to an Active Directory domain. Then you can select a range and go Review > Allow Users to Edit Ranges.

[image]

Click the New button and set a password

[image]

Click the Permissions button and then add users or groups from your domain address book

[image]

As with all other cell protection, this only applies after the sheet is protected.